# sqrt function in C not returning exact value

Tags: c, function, math, sqrt

My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int distance(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
    double value = sqrt(pow((double)(x2- x1),2.0) + pow((double)(y2 - y1),2.0));
    return value;
}
int main(void){
    int A_x, A_y, B_x, B_y, C_x, C_y;
    printf("Enter 1st point:");
    scanf("%d", &A_x);
    scanf("%d", &A_y);
    printf("Enter 2nd point:");
    scanf("%d", &B_x);
    scanf("%d", &B_y);
    printf("Enter 3rd point:");
    scanf("%d", &C_x);
    scanf("%d", &C_y);
    double AB = distance(A_x, A_y, B_x, B_y);
    printf("%.2lf", AB);
    // double powered = pow((double)(A_x- B_x),2.0) + pow((double)(A_y - B_y),2.0);
    // double squared = sqrt(powered);
    // printf("%.2lf", squared);
    double BC = distance(B_x, B_y, C_x, C_y);
    printf("%.2lf", BC);
    double CA = distance(C_x, C_y, A_x, A_y);
    printf("%.2lf", CA);
    if(AB+BC>CA && AB+CA>BC && BC+CA>AB){
        double perimeter = AB+BC+CA;
        printf("Perimeter of triangle = %.2lf",perimeter);
        return 0;
    }else{
        printf("Invalid traingle");
        return -1;
    }
    
}
```

I am getting the following in the compiler:

[image]

I am not exactly sure why I'm getting 2.00 for AB instead of 2.83. Would be glad if someone could explain where I went wrong :)

Comment: Consider using `hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)` instead of custom function.

Comment: Or `hypot(0.0 + x2 - x1, 0.0 + y2 - y1)` to avoid `int` overflow.

Comment: Your problem could have been avoided if you had just used compiler warnings. With `-Wall`, GCC or clang would have informed you that you are losing precision when returning a `double` as an `int`. Never code without compiler warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function distance returns an integer, therefore it truncates the result of the sqrt. You should change the declaration of:

```
 int distance(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
```

to

```
double distance(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
```

Comment: Edit: "returns and integer" --> "returns an integer"